# How to mount toroidal transformer in metal chassis

Tags: electrical

I bought a Hammond 300VA Toroid transformer with these parts:

[image: 1]

And this is the common installation method:

[image: 2]

Complete setup of mounting it to the metal chassis is (the bolt is needed here):

[image: 3]

Some say that if you connect this as instructed.. then the toroid transformer will short and get destroyed even without covering it wirh metal chassis cover. This is because the top and bottom would form close circuit surrounding the flux in the core via the bolt shorting the winding.

Is it true? If true, why does manufacturer give you mounting accessories that can just short it?

So the right way to install it may be just to put it at metal chassis without any metal mount? If you just put it at the bottom of the chassis, would there be flux intermingling with the metal chassis bottom?

Comment: When I use toroides I loop the wire through the ring or bead to suppress motor noise. Most of the times these are left in free air, if mounting is listed by the mfg I don't see how that could be a problem as there are no other wires to induce a current to. maybe you are describing something different than I am used to using or seeing that's why I only left as a comment.

Comment: I googled "How to mount toroidal transformer" and many info came up like https://groupdiy.com/index.php?topic=14996.0 and from a manufacturer site  http://sigatransformers.co.uk/standard-toroids/ that the bolt shouldn't touch top and bottom or the transformer will explode. "Care must be taken when mounting to avoid forming a shorted turn with the fixing bolt.". But I worry whether when I simply let bottom of toroid touch the bottom metal chassis that some of the flux can escape to the metal... see below for the experience of someone with exploding transformer by screw shorted top and bottom.

Comment: read above first... quoting from the first url.. " If you mount the torroid horizontally like this you *MUST* be sure that the bolt DOES NOT touch the top panel of the chasis otherwise you will melt your torroid.  I learned that the hard way and it was a f**king mess and a half.  I had a bolt that was short enough, but I carelessly put something heavy on top of the unit in the rack and it sagged the top panel down enough to touch the bolt, shorting the torroid.  Bad times.  I try to use the shortest bolt possible when mounting torroids now to avoid that."

Comment: Now I see what you are talking about, yes if you add a ferrous core to the toroide the bolt is now a conductor and lines of flux turn into a voltage and shorts to ground some rtv (silicone adhesive sealant ) is what they are reccomending you could also use a wire tie with a screw mount or adhesive stick the mount to capture the wires and hold the toroide in place.

Answer (score 1):

A bolt placed through the middle of the transformer effectively acts as an extra secondary. This secondary can produce very little voltage but potentially very high currents.

As long as this parasitic secondary is open circuit there is no problem. So you *can* mount a toroid in this way. However if the parasitic secondary is shorted through a low resistance path (e.g. the case) things could start to get very hot.

Depending on the application it may be considered wise to fit an insulating plate to the underside of the top of the case in which the transformer is mounted so that even if the cover is crushed it can't short the parasitic secondary.

Comment: Why can't the top steel round plate be considered a low resistant path and short it (why the case is required)?  To aid in understanding. There is something that perflexed me. I can't find any reference about it at google. Why does putting metal above and below the toroid with a bolt short it.. when in fact there are thousands of turns surrounding the toroid core. Remember the top and bottom conductor is not touching any of the winding direct because there are insulation (even rubber insulation). What flux dynamics can do that? Any illustration perhaps?

Comment: Metal above and below the toroid with a bolt is fine PROVIDED that you make sure you avoid having a conductive loop passing through the core.

Comment: Can't the bolt passing through the core act as a conductive loop? Why not? What is the characteristic of a conductive loop?

Comment: Through the core and round the outside, either one is fine but if you complete the loop you will get large currents in your unintentional shorted secondary.

Comment: why is it not "unintentional shorted primary"? why "secondary"? Is the primary in the first layer of the toroid core and the secondary the second layer.. can't they interchange?

Comment: When talking about transformers normally the term "primary" is used for the winding that puts power in to the transformer and "secondary" is used for windings that take power out. Stacking order of the windings is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok. So when you put a conductive loop through the core.. how much voltage or current would the chasis become? Would this be enough to fry the toroid?

Comment: Afaict the primary of a typical mains transfofomer has tens of thousands of turns, so the voltage will be of the oder of millivolts, but the flip side of that is that the current available is potentially extremely high.

Comment: Ok. so if the metal chassis is very big.. then even if the bolt pass through the center of the core.. it would no longer conduct.. would it.. or even if the metal chassis is 1 square meter.. as long as you make it conduct through the core, it would still be shorted?? To what degree is it dependent on chassis size?

Comment: This is the side view... https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/800x600q90/923/9Our8W.jpg  So as long as the top round steel plate or bolt won't touch the top of the metal casing cover (there is ample space).. no problem, right?  And if bolt is connected to top chassis.. there is no size limit before effects would die down?

Comment: Btw.. if you hold a toroid transformer with your hands while it is running and you complete a loop through the core and outside with your fingers.. you would get a shock, right? Anyone has tried this before?

Comment: I doubt putting your finger through the core will do anything noticable, the voltage is very low and the human body is a pretty poor conductor.

Comment: Maybe its because the finger cant produce back emf to produce flux feedback and draw current from primary, right?